# How to use Elasticsearch with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have gone through many blogs and sites about configuring Elasticsearch for MongoDB to index Collections in MongoDB but none of them were straightforward.

Please explain to me a step by step process for installing elasticsearch, which should include:

- configuration
- run in the browser

I am using Node.js with express.js, so please help accordingly.

Comment: Note: Rivers are deprecated

Answer (score 310, accepted):

This answer should be enough to get you set up to follow this tutorial on [Building a functional search component with MongoDB, Elasticsearch, and AngularJS](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-recipe-search-site-angular-elasticsearch/).

If you're looking to use faceted search with data from an API then Matthiasn's [BirdWatch Repo](https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch) is something you might want to look at.

So here's how you can setup a single node Elasticsearch "cluster" to index MongoDB for use in a NodeJS, Express app on a fresh EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance.

Make sure everything is up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install NodeJS.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

[Install MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) - These steps are straight from MongoDB docs.
Choose whatever version you're comfortable with. I'm sticking with v2.4.9 because it seems to be the most recent version [MongoDB-River](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) supports without issues.

Import the MongoDB public GPG Key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Update your sources list.

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Get the 10gen package.

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

Then pick your version if you don't want the most recent. If you are setting your environment up on a windows 7 or 8 machine stay away from v2.6 until they work some bugs out with running it as a service.

```
apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.4.9
```

Prevent the version of your MongoDB installation being bumped up when you update.

```
echo "mongodb-10gen hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Start the MongoDB service.

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Your database files default to /var/lib/mongo and your log files to /var/log/mongo.

Create a database through the mongo shell and push some dummy data into it.

```
mongo YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
db.createCollection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME)
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.insert( { x : i } )
```

Now to [Convert the standalone MongoDB into a Replica Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).

First Shutdown the process.

```
mongo YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

Now we're running MongoDB as a service, so we don't pass in the "--replSet rs0" option in the command line argument when we restart the mongod process. Instead, we put it in the mongod.conf file.

```
vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

Add these lines, subbing for your db and log paths.

```
replSet=rs0
dbpath=YOUR_PATH_TO_DATA/DB
logpath=YOUR_PATH_TO_LOG/MONGO.LOG
```

Now open up the mongo shell again to initialize the replica set.

```
mongo DATABASE_NAME
config = { "_id" : "rs0", "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017" } ] }
rs.initiate(config)
rs.slaveOk() // allows read operations to run on secondary members.
```

Now install Elasticsearch. I'm just following this helpful [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107).

Make sure Java is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless -y
```

Stick with v1.1.x for now until the Mongo-River plugin bug gets fixed in v1.2.1.

```
wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.1.1.deb
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.1.1.deb

curl -L http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper/tarball/master | tar -xz
sudo mv *servicewrapper*/service /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/
sudo rm -Rf *servicewrapper*
sudo /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch install
sudo ln -s `readlink -f /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch` /usr/local/bin/rcelasticsearch
```

Make sure /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml has the following config options enabled if you're only developing on a single node for now:

```
cluster.name: "MY_CLUSTER_NAME"
node.local: true
```

Start the Elasticsearch service.

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Verify it's working.

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

If you see something like this then you're good.

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Chi Demon",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.1.2",
    "build_hash" : "e511f7b28b77c4d99175905fac65bffbf4c80cf7",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-05-22T12:27:39Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.7"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now install the Elasticsearch plugins so it can play with MongoDB.

```
bin/plugin --install com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/1.6.0
bin/plugin --install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.6.0
```

These two plugins aren't necessary but they're good for testing queries and visualizing changes to your indexes.

```
bin/plugin --install mobz/elasticsearch-head
bin/plugin --install lukas-vlcek/bigdesk
```

Restart Elasticsearch.

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

Finally index a collection from MongoDB.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/DATABASE_NAME/_meta -d '{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "db": "DATABASE_NAME",
    "collection": "ACTUAL_COLLECTION_NAME",
    "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
    "gridfs": false
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "ARBITRARY INDEX NAME",
    "type": "ARBITRARY TYPE NAME"
  }
}'
```

Check that your index is in Elasticsearch

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_aliases
```

Check your cluster health.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

It's probably yellow with some unassigned shards. We have to tell Elasticsearch what we want to work with.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_settings' -d '{ "index" : { "number_of_replicas" : 0 } }'
```

Check cluster health again. It should be green now.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

Go play.

Comment: @Duck5auce do have any idea of how to get the result (the elastic search result) by express.js and display in browser either using jade or ejs template for example like app.get('search="google"',function(req,res){});  and thank you for the wonderful answer

Comment: @bibindavid I'd check this resource out. It walks you through creating a server side ES client module you push filtered queries through via two other custom modules. Rendering of the data is still handled on the client, but it should be a decent starting point.

http://sahan.me/posts/dabbling-in-elasticsearch-part-2-with-nodejs/

Github repo located here:  https://github.com/sahan/sahan.github.io/tree/master/resources/elasticnode

Comment: Can u pls tell me which will be better mongoosastic or using mongose and elasticsearch module differently ????

Comment: Its been a year since duck5auce's excellent answer. Think people are now using 10gens [mongo-connector][1] to synchronise a MongoDB cluster with ElasticSearch in real-time. It tails the MongoDB oplog. 

  [1]: https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20ElasticSearch

Comment: As of v1.5.0, the river service has been deprecated. While you can still use river plugins, its not advised as its could cease to exist in future versions.

Comment: @duck5auce Please update this answer, it is out dated. [River has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/rivers/current/index.html)

Comment: Apologies for the much needed edit. I will be updating this over the course of this week.

Comment: Another great example can be found here: https://medium.com/@xoor/indexing-mongodb-with-elasticsearch-2c428b676343

Answer (score 37):

Using river can present issues when your operation scales up. River will use a ton of memory when under heavy operation. I recommend implementing your own elasticsearch models, or if you're using mongoose you can build your elasticsearch models right into that or use [mongoosastic](https://github.com/jamescarr/mongoosastic) which essentially does this for you.

Another disadvantage to Mongodb River is that you'll be stuck using mongodb 2.4.x branch, and ElasticSearch 0.90.x. You'll start to find that you're missing out on a lot of really nice features, and the mongodb river project just doesn't produce a usable product fast enough to keep stable. That said Mongodb River is definitely not something I'd go into production with. It's posed more problems than its worth. It will randomly drop write under heavy load, it will consume lots of memory, and there's no setting to cap that. Additionally, river doesn't update in realtime, it reads oplogs from mongodb, and this can delay updates for as long as 5 minutes in my experience.

We recently had to rewrite a large portion of our project, because its a weekly occurrence that something goes wrong with ElasticSearch. We had even gone as far as to hire a Dev Ops consultant, who also agrees that its best to move away from River.

**UPDATE:**
Elasticsearch-mongodb-river now supports ES v1.4.0 and mongodb v2.6.x. However, you'll still likely run into performance problems on heavy insert/update operations as this plugin will try to read mongodb's oplogs to sync. If there are a lot of operations since the lock(or latch rather) unlocks, you'll notice extremely high memory usage on your elasticsearch server. If you plan on having a large operation, river is not a good option. The developers of ElasticSearch still recommend you to manage your own indexes by communicating directly with their API using the client library for your language, rather than using river. This isn't really the purpose of river. Twitter-river is a great example of how river should be used. Its essentially a great way to source data from outside sources, but not very reliable for high traffic or internal use.

Also consider that mongodb-river falls behind in version, as its not maintained by ElasticSearch Organization, its maintained by a thirdparty. Development was stuck on v0.90 branch for a long time after the release of v1.0, and when a version for v1.0 was released it wasn't stable until elasticsearch released v1.3.0. Mongodb versions also fall behind. You may find yourself in a tight spot when you're looking to move to a later version of each, especially with ElasticSearch under such heavy development, with many very anticipated features on the way. Staying up on the latest ElasticSearch has been very important as we rely heavily on constantly improving our search functionality as its a core part of our product.

All in all you'll likely get a better product if you do it yourself. Its not that difficult. Its just another database to manage in your code, and it can easily be dropped in to your existing models without major refactoring.

Comment: Do you have a link or an advice where i can indexing i.e author info into publication index since publication and author are in 2 collections and link via referenceone and referencemany

Comment: Read this for some background https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

Comment: The this would explain how you join/relate data https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html

Comment: Elasticsearch is a document storage DB, rather than a relational one. It's not impossible to relate data in elasticsearch, but denormalization is more likely to occur, but can be managed with additional logic(there are plugins). The most common way to relate data, as state in the link above, is to store an ID reference in the relative document. Make sure you store this ID in a field which is set to `not_analyzed`, otherwise you will have trouble querying for it, do to the way analyzed fields get tokenized.

Answer (score 5):

River is a good solution once you want to have a almost real time synchronization and general solution.

If you have data in MongoDB already and want to ship it very easily to Elasticsearch like "one-shot" you can try my package in Node.js https://github.com/itemsapi/elasticbulk.

It's using Node.js streams so you can import data from everything what is supporting streams (i.e. MongoDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL, JSON files, etc)

Example for MongoDB to Elasticsearch:

Install packages:

```
npm install elasticbulk
npm install mongoose
npm install bluebird
```

Create script i.e. script.js:

```
const elasticbulk = require('elasticbulk');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/your_database_name', {
  useMongoClient: true
});

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

var Page = mongoose.model('Page', new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  categories: Array
}), 'your_collection_name');

// stream query 
var stream = Page.find({
}, {title: 1, _id: 0, categories: 1}).limit(1500000).skip(0).batchSize(500).stream();

elasticbulk.import(stream, {
  index: 'my_index_name',
  type: 'my_type_name',
  host: 'localhost:9200',
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log('Importing finished');
})
```

Ship your data:

```
node script.js
```

It's not extremely fast but it's working for millions of records (thanks to streams).

Answer (score 5):

Here I found another good option to migrate your MongoDB data to Elasticsearch.
A go daemon that syncs mongodb to elasticsearch in realtime.
Its the Monstache. Its available at :  [Monstache](https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/)

Below the initial setp to configure and use it.

Step 1:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --replSet test
```

Step 2 :

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
Server has startup warnings:
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 3 : Verify the replication.

```
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
        "set" : "test",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:39:00.380Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(2),
        "syncingTo" : "",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                }
        },
        "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1547811517, 1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "localhost:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 736,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:38:57Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1547810805, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:26:45Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 4.
    Download the "https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/releases".
    Unzip the download and adjust your PATH variable to include the path to the folder for your platform.
    GO to cmd and type `"monstache -v"`
    # 4.13.1
    Monstache uses the TOML format for its configuration. Configure the file for migration named config.toml

Step 5.

My config.toml -->

```
mongo-url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?replicaSet=test"
elasticsearch-urls = ["http://localhost:9200"]

direct-read-namespaces = [ "admin.users" ]

gzip = true
stats = true
index-stats = true

elasticsearch-max-conns = 4
elasticsearch-max-seconds = 5
elasticsearch-max-bytes = 8000000 

dropped-collections = false
dropped-databases = false

resume = true
resume-write-unsafe = true
resume-name = "default"
index-files = false
file-highlighting = false
verbose = true
exit-after-direct-reads = false

index-as-update=true
index-oplog-time=true
```

Step 6.

```
D:\15-1-19>monstache -f config.toml
```

[image: Monstache Running...]

[image: Confirm Migrated Data at Elasticsearch]

[image: Add Record at Mongo]

[image: Monstache Captured the event and migrate the data to elasticsearch]

Answer (score 4):

I found mongo-connector useful. It is form Mongo Labs (MongoDB Inc.) and can be used now with Elasticsearch 2.x

Elastic 2.x doc manager: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/elastic2-doc-manager

mongo-connector creates a pipeline from a MongoDB cluster to one or more target systems, such as Solr, Elasticsearch, or another MongoDB cluster. It synchronizes data in MongoDB to the target then tails the MongoDB oplog, keeping up with operations in MongoDB in real-time. It has been tested with Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3+. Detailed documentation is available on the wiki.

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector
https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20ElasticSearch

Answer (score 3):

Here how to do this on mongodb 3.0. I used this nice [blog](http://backslash451.github.io/articles/Running-ElasticSearch-with-MongoDB-and-Kibana/)

1. Install mongodb.
2. Create data directories:

> ```
> $ mkdir RANDOM_PATH/node1
> $ mkdir RANDOM_PATH/node2> 
> $ mkdir RANDOM_PATH/node3
> ```

3. Start Mongod instances

> ```
> $ mongod --replSet test --port 27021 --dbpath node1
> $ mongod --replSet test --port 27022 --dbpath node2
> $ mongod --replSet test --port 27023 --dbpath node3
> ```

4. Configure the Replica Set:

> ```
> $ mongo
> config = {_id: 'test', members: [ {_id: 0, host: 'localhost:27021'}, {_id: 1, host: 'localhost:27022'}]};    
> rs.initiate(config);
> ```

5. Installing Elasticsearch:

> ```
> a. Download and unzip the [latest Elasticsearch][2] distribution
>
> b. Run bin/elasticsearch to start the es server.
>
> c. Run curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/ to confirm it is working.
> ```

6. Installing and configuring the MongoDB River:

> $ bin/plugin --install
>   com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb
>
> $ bin/plugin --install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments

7. Create the “River” and the Index:

> curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:8080/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
>         "type": "mongodb", 
>         "mongodb": { 
>             "db": "mydb", 
>             "collection": "foo"
>         },
>         "index": {
>             "name": "name", 
>             "type": "random" 
>         }
>       }'

8. Test on browser:

   http://localhost:9200/_search?q=home

Comment: ElasticSearch has deprecated river plugins. This is most certainly not the best way to maintain a search index.

Answer (score 3):

Since mongo-connector now appears dead, my company decided to build a tool for using Mongo change streams to output to Elasticsearch.

Our initial results look promising. You can check it out at https://github.com/electionsexperts/mongo-stream. We're still early in development, and would welcome suggestions or contributions.

Comment: This project also appears to be dead. Last update was 2019.

Comment: Sadly the company that made it (which I worked for) laid off most of its staff in early 2019. I do still have access to the repository, and might be able to track down some of the authors if you wanted to try to resurrect it.

Comment: That sounds like a fun project...
Maybe 6 months down the road. I'm cobbling together Logstash right now as kind of a quick/emergency patch, and I don't think I can afford to put more time into things than I already have. Not for a bit, anyways.