# How to delete a field mapping in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have an index with following mapping

```
{
   "testmap": {
      "mappings": {
         "user": {
            "properties": {
               "plans": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "user": {
                        "type": "long"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "status": {
                  "type": "integer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to delete status field mapping. I don't mind to loose data on that field. Is there any option to delete status field. 
**Tried**

```
curl -XDELETE http://192.168.2.2:9200/testmap/user/status
{"found":false,"_index":"testmap","_type":"user","_id":"status","_version":1
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350813/elasticsearch-how-do-you-delete-a-mapping-type-without-deleting-an-entire-index/57964499#57964499

Answer (score 20):

You cannot delete the `status` field from this mapping. If you really need to get rid of this field, you'll have to create another mapping without `status` field and reindex your data. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25471930/1797393).

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to change the mapping type on the status field, then you can't delete it, but you can change it to a `multi_field` type, which indexes the field with multiple option sets.

Old data won't be indexed to the new field, but index requests moving forward will. In some use cases, it's a decently alternative for "delete the index and create a new one with a new mapping".

https://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html

Comment: The OP does not want to replace `status` field with another. Hence `multi_field` is not useful in this case.

Comment: Understood. But the impetus for deleting a mapping is often to replace it with a different one; `multi_field` can frequently meet that need without having to recreate the entire mapping.