# Kibana not taking data types

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying my hands on ELK stack. I have a problem with my Kibana. One of the fields in my data is of type integer but on the Kibana it shows the type as undefined. Please find below the sample data I am working with.

```
  {
      "took": 6,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AVivMgCnKd2m9Wr-3jBk",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "message": "product10,990\r",
              "@version": "1",
              "@timestamp": "2016-11-29T08:27:18.792Z",
              "path": "/Users/B0079855/Documents/SERVERS/logstash-2.2.2/samples/products.csv",
              "host": "LTB0079855-MAC.local",
              "product_name": "product10",
              "product_price": 990
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Kibana not identifying product_price as integer.

logstash conf:

```
input { 
   file { 
     path => "{filepath}" 
     # to read from the beginning of file 
     start_position => beginning
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   } 
} 

filter { 
    csv { 
      columns => ["product_name", "product_price"] 
    } 
    mutate { 
      convert => { "product_price" => "integer" } 
    } 
} 

output { 
    elasticsearch { 
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "products" 
    } 
    stdout { codec => rubydebug } 
}
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: I am reading data via logstash from a file and I am converting it to integer in the filter. My logstash configuration for filter is like: `filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["product_name", "product_price"]
    }
    mutate {
     convert => { "product_price" => "integer" }
   }
}`

Comment: Could you show us the logstash conf. From which type are you trying to convert from? Are you using the `mutate` plugin? What if you don't convert it from your logstash, and update it through your mapping as I've mentioned in the answer below?

Comment: In case I do it via update statement I will have to do it for every index. My logstash conf looks like.  `input {
  file {
    path => "{filepath}"
    # to read from the beginning of file
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["product_name", "product_price"]
    }
    mutate {
     convert => { "product_price" => "integer" }
   }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { 
     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => "products"
 }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}`

Comment: I am reading it from a csv file. A sample data set is like `productA,550`

Comment: I've updated the answer with the edit part. Try doing the conversion within the csv tag itself like i've mentioned in the answer below. Make sure you remove the mutate from your filter. Let me know whether you get the required output.

Comment: I dropped the index and created again making the chages. Its working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to make a change in the filter configuration, before the convert you are required to add mutate.

Comment: filter { 
    csv { 
      columns => ["product_name", "product_price"] 
    } 
    mutate { 
      convert => { "product_price" => "integer" } 
    } 
}

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't mapped your fields using [Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping), you could do something like below in order to create a `mapping` before you create the index:

`PUT` request: http://yourhost:9200/yourindex

Request BODY:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": { <--- document_type value in logstash conf
      "properties": {
        "product_price": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If not you can even update the index mapping back again with a `PUT` mapping API:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type' -d '
{
    "yout_type" : {
        "properties" : {              
          //your new mapping properties
          "product_price": {
             "type": "integer"
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Hope this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471715/create-or-update-mapping-in-elasticsearch) helps as well.

**EDIT:**

In your case since you're converting it using `logstash`, you're tryign to convert it outside of `csv` plugin. Try converting it within the plugin itself;

```
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["product_name", "product_price"] 
    mutate {
       convert => { "product_price" => "integer" }
    } 
  }
}
```