# error while starting elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

It was starting all fine a few minutes ago. Then i tried to integrate mongo-db with it. using this link: [How to use Elasticsearch with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb)

Now its not starting with the following error:

```
viki@viki-pc:~/INSTALLED/elasticsearch-1.4.1/bin$ ./elasticsearch
[2014-12-05 17:59:59,486][INFO ][node                     ] [Iridia] version[1.4.1], pid[23976], build[89d3241/2014-11-26T15:49:29Z]
[2014-12-05 17:59:59,486][INFO ][node                     ] [Iridia] initializing ...
[2014-12-05 17:59:59,531][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Iridia] loaded [QuartzPlugin, mapper-attachments], sites []



[2014-12-05 18:00:00,889][INFO ][org.codelibs.elasticsearch.quartz.service.ScheduleService] [Iridia] Creating Scheduler...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

{1.4.1}: Initialization Failed ...
1) NoClassDefFoundError[org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder]
ClassNotFoundException[org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder]
```

I also installed

```
sudo pip install mongo-connector
```

Any idea what might be wrong here ??

Comment: Do you mean using a river to import data from mongodb to elasticsearch?

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem at least try to write it or delete your question!

Comment: @eliasah: yes i am trying to import data from mongodb to elasticsearch. And no i am still waiting for a solution. Any idea what might be the issue here.

Comment: reinstalled everything from scratch. and now facing this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329307/elastic-search-failed-to-start-with-timeout-while-connecting-with-database