# Optimization - find on all fields in Mongoose MongoDB schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

> We needed to challenge our database approach and need your help

We needed to search a word/phrase in all fields of a Mongoose schema.

Let's say the schema is like this:

```
var sampleSchema = new Schema({
    fieldABC: String,
    fieldDEF: String,
    fieldGHI: String
});
```

We need to write a find query which will search for a word in all fields in a document of the collection:

```
db.sampleCollection.find({
  $or: [{
    fieldABC: "wordToSearch"
  }, {
    fieldDEF: "wordToSearch"
  }, {
    fieldGHI: "wordToSearch"
  }]
})
```

It's possible for us to write the above query but it looks very inefficient - is there some better and faster approach to this?

[In the year 2015, it was not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807857/2404470), is there any change in this?

Comment: You can try [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes)

Comment: @Veeram You seems to be talking about indexing, I'm talking about data retrieval

Comment: You create a index first and then you use [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#examples) to find text in documents.

Comment: @Veeram your text search suggestion is exactly what we were looking for. That must be posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929774/optimization-find-on-all-fields-in-mongoose-mongodb-schema?noredirect=1#comment82828486_47929774) by [@Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram)

## Step 1:

Create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes)

```
db.sampleCollection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

## Step 2:

Use the text index to search the word in concern

```
db.sampleCollection.find( { $text: { $search: "wordToSearch" } })
```