# Optimization on excluding some documents from text search result set based on a field's values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, optimization, mongoose

In our MongoDB-Node.js-Mongoose setup:

We've created a [text search index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944720/2404470) and we're able to find a word from the collection with it too:

```
db.sampleCollection.find( { $text: { $search: "wordToSearch" } })
```

So far, there is no problem...

We've a requirement that if the documents in the `sampleCollection` have a field `private` set to `true` then we need to exclude those documents from the result set.

Probably we can add something like this:

```
.where({ private: true})
```

It looks like an extra call and non-efficient. Is there some better and faster way to do this?

Comment: Something like `db.sampleCollection.find( { private: { $ne:true }, $text: { $search: "wordToSearch" } } })`

Comment: @Veeram Thanks, will check this and update!! Is there something to justify that it is faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say to MongoDB: "Get me all documents that have text 'wordToSearch' and have a property named 'private' NOT equal to true", then the following query should work:

```
db.sampleCollection.find({ private: { $ne: true }, $text: { $search: "wordToSearch" } })
```

Comment: cool, is there any justification for it's performance perspectives.

Comment: From MongoDB website (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/):


The inequality operator $ne is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection.


So I guess it does not have any performance implications. (This last setence was from me :))

Comment: It means that this is not something which we were looking for. The question was *Is there some better and faster way to do this?*

Comment: I don't think there is some faster way to do this. The query should be fast enough, it is just a condition added to the initial query and not much to be done about it. It does not decrease or improve performance.