# Integrate Elasticsearch with PostgreSQL while using Sails.js with Waterline ORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, sails.js

I am trying to integrate Elasticsearch with Sails.js and my database isn't MongoDB: I use PostgreSQL, so this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb) doesn't help.

I have installed Elasticsearch on my Ubuntu box and now it's running successfully. I also installed this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/waterline-elasticsearch#find) on my Sails project, but I cannot create indexes on my existing models.

How can I define indexes on my models, and how can I search using Elasticsearch inside my Models?

What are the hooks which I need to define it inside models?

Comment: [Please check here answer is already to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb)

Comment: I edited question, hopefully, you won't mind. I added postgresql in the title to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ManjeetThakur That article mentions using river which isn't  the recommended way now. And is deprecated. Also OP want solution for postgresql.

Comment: @Ahmed What more do you want in the answer? I have given step by step clue how to solve this issue. If you look, grace period is expiring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-elastic) you could find a pretty straightforward package (sails-elastic). It operates by configs directly from elasticsearch itself.

[Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) and [index creation in particular](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of approach to solve this issue. The recommended way is to use logstash by elasticsearch which I have given in detail.
I would list most of the approaches that I know here:

1. Using Logstash

   ```
   curl https://download.elastic.co/logstash/logstash/logstash-2.3.2.tar.gz > logstash.tar.gz
   tar -xzf logstash.tar.gz
   cd logstash-2.3.2
   ```

   Install the jdbc input plugin:

   ```
   bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc
   ```

   Then download postgresql jdbc driver.

   ```
   curl https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar > postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar
   ```

   Now create a configuration file for logstash to use jdbc input as input.conf:

   ```
   input {
     jdbc {
       jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/khurrambaig/Downloads/logstash-2.3.2/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/khurrambaig"
       jdbc_user => "khurrambaig"
       jdbc_password => ""
       schedule => "* * * * *"
       statement => 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE "updatedAt" > :sql_last_value'
       type => "customer"
     }
     jdbc {
       jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/khurrambaig/Downloads/logstash-2.3.2/postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar"
       jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
       jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/khurrambaig"
       jdbc_user => "khurrambaig"
       jdbc_password => ""
       schedule => "* * * * *"
       statement => 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE "updatedAt" > :sql_last_value'
       type => "employee"
     }

     # add more jdbc inputs to suit your needs
   }
   output {
       elasticsearch {
           index => "khurrambaig"
           document_type => "%{type}"   # <- use the type from each input
           document_id => "%{id}" # <- To avoid duplicates
           hosts => "localhost:9200"
       }
   }
   ```

   Now run logstash using the above file:

   ```
   bin/logstash -f input.conf
   ```

   For every model that you want to insert as a document(table) type in a index(database, khurrambaig here), use appropriate SQL statement ( SELECT * FROM employee WHERE "updatedAt" > :sql_last_value here). Here I have use sql_last_value to put only updated data only. You can do scheduling also and many stuff in logstash. Here I am using every minute. For more details refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html).

   To see the documents which has been inserted into index for a particular type:

   ```
   curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/khrm/user/_search?pretty=true'
   ```

   This will list all the documents under customer models for my case. Look into elastic search api. Use that. Or use nodejs official [client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js).
2. Using jdbc input

   https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc

   You can read its readme. It's quite straightforward. But this doesn't provide scheduling and many of the things that are provided by logstash.
3. Using [sails-elastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-elastic)

   You need to use multiple adapters as given in README.

   But this isn't recommended because it will slow down your requests. For every creation, updation and deletion, you will be calling two dbs : elastic search and postgresql.

   In logstash, indexing of documents is independent of requests. This approach is used by many including wikipedia. Also you remain independent of framework. Today you are using sails, tomorrow you might use something else but you don't need to change anything in case of logstash if you still use postgresql. (If you change db, even then many of the db's input are available and in case of change from any sql rdbms to another, you just need to change to jdbc driver)

There's [zombodb](https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb) also but it work for pre 2.0 elastic only currently (Support for > ES 2.0 coming also).

Comment: ZomboDB author here.  ZDB doesn't yet support ES 2.x, but it will soon.  I might be a bit biased, but it really is the only thing that properly ties ES & PG together so that your ES queries are a) transactionally correct, b) automatically synchronized, and c) doesn't require application code to deal with ES.

Comment: @EricB.Ridge OK. Thanks for the information. Will update.

Comment: ZomboDB now supports ES 2.4 and ES 5.6 support is nearly complete.