# Elastic Search 2.4.1 and MongoDB 3.2 integration

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, elasticsearch-plugin

i am using `ElasticSearch2.4.1` and `MongoDB3.2`

In earlier version(1.x) of ES there were rivers available to connect with `MongoDB` directly.
i followed:
[How to use Elasticsearch with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb)

`MongoDB` River Plugin details for ElasticSearch
https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb

but the `ES` `version 2.X` onward there is no concept of `rivers`.
i have gone through lots of blogs and sites but not getting plenty of information to connect `ES` with `MongoDB` for these latest versions.

i found `MongoStatic` and `Mongolastic` can be useful to make communication with `MongoDB` to `ES`

`mongolastic`: https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic

`mongolastic`: https://www.compose.com/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/

but these articles are bit complex than river plugin terminology we used because i am not having much idea about `node js` and `yaml` file configuration

is there any other other way to connect `ES` with `MongoDB`, i am using `Postman` to send rest request to `ES`.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, rivers were removed in Elasticsearch 2.0. You can use Logstash to ship documents from MongoDB to Elasticsearch, this is the relevant [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-mongodb.html)

Note the comment at the top of the page, that's a community based plugin so you will need to install it as it isn't installed in the default Logstash installation.

Comment: i have to create ES index at run time and getting the MogoDB collection info from client through rest call.
as per my understanding Logstash it is separate entity and does not take 'input' from client ie rest request.