# Integrate MongoDB with elasticsearch macOSX

Tags: java, mongodb, macos, elasticsearch

I am trying to integrate MongoDB with Elasticsearch 5.5.2. Can anyone provide me the instructions on how do i proceed? I have not found proper links for integrating them. 
I have understood that we need to install mongo-connector/river-mongodb but i am unable to install it.

I have found this command

```
pip install 'mongo-connector[elastic5]'
```

but this is for python environment.
I am using java environment.

I have also tried these following commands:

```
my/elasticsearch/location/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.4.0 
my/elasticsearch/location/bin/plugin -install richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/1.4.0
```

I get this:

```
 my/elasticsearch/location/bin/plugin: is a directory
```

I am using macOSX. I have already installed ElasticSearch and MongoDB.
Thanks.

Comment: What you need actually?? Install ES??

Comment: integrate elasticsearch with MongoDB.

Comment: Have you installed both of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Elasticsearch with MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb)

Comment: Yes, i have installed both of them.they are running properly.  I have edited that in my question.

Comment: @nafas it is for Nodejs environment and also, the setup is for ubuntu.

Comment: @VaibhavSavala the ideas are the same mate, plugin is a folder should give you the clue here. u need to install plugin using `bin/(elasticsearch-)plugin`

Comment: Now i get my/elasticsearch/location/bin/elasticsearch-plugin is not a directory when i run that command.

Comment: @VaibhavSavala mate, if I was you before understanding elasticsearch, I would go and understand the mac's filesystem. `my/elastisearch/location/bin/elasticsearch-plugin` means to go to folder `my` then subfolder `elasticsearch` then subfolder `location` then subfolder `bin` then `run` elasticssearch-plugin script

Comment: @nafas  Okay Cool. I got what you meant. I am a bit weak in understanding linux commands. Thanks for the info. Btw, i have looked up for alternatives and i found out that river plugin is not the popular choice. it will be deprecated soon. We can use logstash to integrate mongoDB with elasticsearch.

Comment: @VaibhavSavala great stuff mate,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the MongoConnector Plugin. It supports data sync between MongoDB and Elastic Search.

1) Install Mongo Connector in your server.

`pip install mongo-connector`

2) Install Doc Manager based on target system. There are various implementations for Doc Manager based on the Target system. Install the one that supports Elastic Search and in particular the version that you have. Eg)

pip install 'mongo-connector[elastic5]'

3) Start Mongo Connector with configurations of the source(mongodb) and target systems. Eg)

mongo-connector -m : -t http://localhost:8983/solr> -d

Now data will be automatically synced up between the two systems.

For more information, use the following links,

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mongo-connector

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20ElasticSearch

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: @samo I currently have a node.js dyno running on Heroku and I have a cloud hosed ElasticSearch. To use mongo connector does it mean I have to have a python dyno running too?