# ELK stack - how to search through mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using the elk stack for the first time and I can import data with logstash but how do I link my mongodb to elastic instead?

Also, what is the best way to import bulk data?

I'm using the MEAN stack and the newest version of elk 5+. I am not using beats like filebeats but am willing to use if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're using logstash successfully, then you don't need filebeats. (Although filebeats is much better than logstash).

I think you're confused about the other terms.. You don't hook up mongodb to elastic. When using the ELK stack, logstash is intended to send your logs to elasticsearch, and kibana is the UI layer to view your data.

If you really want to use mongodb (although I don't recommend), then you're using mongodb instead of elasticsearch.

Comment: Okay, so I would just somehow import the data from mongo then process that through logstash?

Answer (score 0):

If you are after searching MongoDB data in elasticsearch you will need to import it (from Mongo to Elasticsearch)
There are a few ways, one of them is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24119066/6079633 - but i don't think it supports elastic 5

And there is this one  https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic - which is according to elasticsearch website: "A tool that clones data from ElasticSearch to MongoDB and vice versa"

Answer (score 0):

*I know this answer could be late, but it may help other people.*

If you need a tool to transfer your data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch, have a look into this mongoose plugin https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/tree/master/docs, it's a great tool for automatically indexing MongoDB models into elasticsearch.

and you can transfer your collection data through [indexing an existing collection](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/tree/master/docs#indexing-an-existing-collection) in MongoDB