# Query through multiple collections mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a situation that I'm trying to solve with mongoDB. I have a system that need to crawl many of websites and store the data in mongoDB. The problem is that I'm running this crawler all day, so I'm going to massively perform inserts and deletes on the database, and I have a website that make queries on that data. What I want to know is how the changes will impact on the performance of the queries, what would be the best approach?

Comment: You can index the data to any distributed search engine like `elasticsearch`, so that you can retrieve the data quickly.

Comment: Do you know if elasticsearch can operate through multiple collections?

Comment: yes, you can create different indexes for each collections if you want.

Comment: These links may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb, https://discuss.elastic.co/t/per-mongodb-shard-per-elasticsearch-cluster/9454