# MongoDB Atlas Search - How to filter search score

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, search, mongodb-atlas-search

Is there is any fine way to filter result on the basis of searchScore. For eg, I got 15000 results and I want to filter out result by using $match by keeping results with score greater than 15. Problem is that as the number of results increase $match will respond slow

```
product.aggregate([
  {
    '$search': {
      'text': {
        'query': 'harry potter', 
        'path': 'title'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'score': {
        '$meta': 'searchScore'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'score': {
        '$gt': 15
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: try looking at elastic with MongoDB  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846971/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`compound`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/compound/#std-label-compound-ref) and add a `filter` clause with [`range`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/range/).

```
product.aggregate([
  {
    '$search': {
      'compound': { 
       'must' : [ {
          'text': { 'query': 'harry potter', 'path': 'title'} 
          }],
       'filter' : {
            'range' : { path: "score", gt: 15 } 
        } 
      }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'score': {
        '$meta': 'searchScore'
      }
    }
  }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hey @Doug, Thank you for the help. But its not working. When I am using filter clause with range inside compound, it doesn't return any response. There might be a reason behind this is that it might not getting score filed before project stage.

Comment: @AnkitSaini might be too polite to make it clear that the reason it is not working is that, the score filed is only available after the project stage, so referring to it before that in the search stage will not be working. I just tried and then realize that.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is an index. Indexes are secondary data structures used by databases for faster access to certain data you want it to keep track of.

Usually, when you run a selection query, MongoDB does a "collection scan" where it scans every single document in the collection to find the required data. However, with an index, the database engine keeps track of where the required data is and the number of documents it needs to scan is limited. By default, there's an index on _id since the database needs to ensure that no other index has the same _id for every insert or update. You can create your own index on any field in the collection, examples in the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

However, be aware that creating indexes will have an impact on the performance inserts and updates since it needs to create an index on every new document inserted. Moreover, creating indexes will take space since they need to be stored in addition to the data. If you have enough RAM to fit the entire index structure in memory, you'll get the best performance.